# Using Checkbox Filter in GI for an API Call Always Returning True

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use a checkbox as a filter for a GI, but every time I make the API request, the checkbox always returns as true, even if I default the checkbox to false.

Here is the GI setup for the filter:

[image]

As you can see, I have 3 check boxes. Despite the settings displayed, all 3 return true, even if not given a value:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I did not include any values for the bools, so expected behavior should be ShowOpenHold and Test2 as false and Test only as true. Despite this, all three filter parameters are true. Is this a known issue, or is there something special I need to add so that it does not default to true all the time?

Answer (score 0):

In GIs you should always explicitly set the filter values in the body of the PUT request.
Otherwise the behavior is not defined.

Comment: I did not show the screen shots, but yes, I did set the values in the body and it still failed to read. Even if set to false, it still comes over in the DB as true. I will post screen shots at a later time.